# How to set min height of bars in Stacked-bar chart

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I am using dc.js library to create stacked bar charts. I want to set a minimum height of a each bar or single stacked bar height so that it get shown all the time in the chart.
[image]
Adding screenshot of the chart where one bar is so small that its not getting displayed in the chart.

Comment: add some negative range to the y-axis

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far, and read the advice on [how to write a good question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I have no clue how to do that, its like there is no direct support from dc.js library to set min length of the bars in stacked charts. So I don't have any code snippet which can be posted here.

Comment: It might be possible to use a different type of scale on the y axis to mitigate the problem, but that requires you to post what you have done so far as I don't know what you're currently using.

Comment: Please use the [dc.js] tag to ask questions about the charting library. [dc] is a command line calculator tool. @ialarmedalien is right, you could try a log scale to make the difference between bar heights lesser. dc.js will not apply a minimum height because that would be misleading.